# Concatenate a string based on string found in a column

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the following table

```
Table - City

City           Country
Chicago/IL       USA         
Dallas/TX        USA
```

I want to create the spark SQL which returns the output like this

```
City             State/Country
Chicago/IL       Illinois/USA         
Dallas/TX        Texas/USA
```

So the logic should be when the IL string is found in City column to add "Illinois" in State/Country Column and when TX string is found in City column to add "Texas"
How I can achieve it?

Comment: Is there a reason there isn't a state field, and you are delimiting your city field with a `/` ?  IMHO I think you should have 4 fields ... `|   city    |    state_short    |    state_long    |    country    |`

Comment: you need definatekly a tabke where IL <.->ILLinois are repüresenetd for all state name

Comment: What do you want from us? also https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. have a nice read.

Comment: What did you try and what failed? What specific problem you have? What is your efforts?